# Global and local variable conflict in Event function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I know this has been asked a lot of times before, but all the reference questions dealt with the scoping issue. I can't wrap my head around this. I even debugged it and in the Call Stack, it shows the value of the count as `String` but the `innerTExt` doesn't changes to **String**. But when I change the name of the `count` variable inside the function, it works fine. Since, local variable and global variables have different Call Stack, it should be perfectly okay.Can anybody explain how is it working on Call Stack and behind the scenes?

```html
<div><h1>Hello World !</h1></div>
    <button class="event-button">Click me</button>
    <div class="counter">count:0</div>
    <script>
      const button = document.querySelector(".event-button");
      const count = document.querySelector(".counter");
      button.addEventListener("click", function () {
        const count = "String";
        count.innerText = count;
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: It seems that when you write `count.innerText = count` you are expecting the `count` on the left to refer to a different value from the one on the `right`. It's not at all clear why you have any expectation of that working.

Comment: "*all the reference questions dealt with the scoping issue*" - well did you understand their explanations? It **is** a scoping issue. Fix your variable names. "*Since, local variable and global variables have different Call Stack, it should be perfectly okay*" - no. Variable scope and the call stack have nothing to do with each other, so I'm not even sure what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has absolutely nothing to do with the call stack.

You have [shadowed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) `count` inside the function.

This means you have two variables named `count` in different scopes.

When you access `count` inside the function, you access the closest one, which is the one you defined inside the function.

You do not have access to the one in the wider scope.

```html
<button class="event-button">Click me</button>
<div class="counter">count:0</div>
<script>
    const button = document.querySelector(".event-button");
    const count = document.querySelector(".counter"); // <= The value assigned to the count variable in the outer scope is set to the return value of the querySelector method: an HTMLElement object
    button.addEventListener("click", function () {
        // The value assigned to the count variable in the inner
        // scope (different from the 'count' found in the outer 
        // scope is set to a String value)
        const count = "String";
        // The count variable (a String) does not have a property `innerText`
        count.innerText = count;

        // What you want to do instead is replace the two lines above with this one:
        count.innerText = "String"; // <= Just keep this one and count will reflect he variable declared in the outer scope
    });
</script>
```

Comment: But if I change this to ```const count1 = "String"; count.innerText = count1; });``` this changes the InnerText, why ?

Comment: @Arif — Because you then have **one** variable named `count` and **one** variable named `count1` instead of **two** variables named `count`.

Comment: Okay, I got this finally. Thanks for explaining it nicely. I was implicitly thinking that in the statement `count.innerText = count;`, the `count` here would be accessing the global variable and then using the local variable when we are assigning.

Comment: So, in this flow, can we change the Global value variables with binding or some other inbuilt Js function ?

Comment: No. Don't shadow variables.

Comment: @Daedalus — It's only a string because of shadowing. The variable they're *trying* to access contains an element.